# Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 30: Proof Verification for One-sided Limits

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I'd like to have some proof verification since I'm not fully confident on my solutions for Spivak's Calculus Chapter 5 Problem 30, which has three parts. Below are the the problem statements and my proof attempts.

1. Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-} f(-x)$.

Proof attempt:

Start with the LHS of the equation. If $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = l$ for some real number $l$, then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that when $0 < x < \delta$, $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. We want to show that there exists some $\delta' < 0$ such that when $\delta' < x < 0$, $|f(-x) - l| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

The inequality $0 < x < \delta$ gives us $-\delta < -x < 0$ and $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. In other words we have that when there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $-\delta < -x < 0$, we have $|f(- (-x)) -l | < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$. So by the definition of a one-sided limit $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(-x) = l$. If a limit exists, it is unique so the two sides of the equation are equal.

2. Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(|x|) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$.

Proof Attempt:

Assume the RHS limit evaluates to some value $l$; then there exists $\delta > 0$, such that when $0 < |x| < \delta$, $|f(|x|) - l| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Note that if $x \geq 0$, $|x| = x$. Hence if $x > 0$, then $0 < x < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. If a limit exists, it is unique so $\lim_{x\to 0} f(|x|) = l = \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$.

3. Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$.

Proof Attempt:

Assume the LHS limit evaluates to some value $l$. Then when $0 < |x| < \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$, $|f(x^2) - l| < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$. Then if $0< |x| < \delta^2$, $0 < \sqrt{|x|} < \delta$ so $|f(\sqrt{|x|}^2) - l| < \epsilon$ and $f(\sqrt{|x|}^2) = f(x)$ so $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$. Hence there exists some $\delta' > 0$ and $\delta' = \delta^2$ where $0 < x < \delta'$ implies that $|f(x) - l| < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$. If a limit exists, it is unique so $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2) = l = \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$.

I would appreciate any advice especially for part 1. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add some hypotheses. Where is $f$ defined? Why do any of these limits exist?

Comment: @zhw. Is it sufficient to say $f$ is defined when $x$ is within some bound around $0$, or would I have to say $f$ is defined on all real numbers (I guess that would be too strict of a condition on $f$?). And is sufficient to just assume that both the RHS and LHS limit exist? I'm a bit confused as to how extensive these hypotheses have to be stated.

Also, it seems that in part 1,2, and 3, if one of the two limits (LHS or RHS) exists, the other must as well since each side of the equation is evaluating the same values for $x$, the positive values.

Comment: I think your proofs are correct and just to be supplemented with a little bit extra stuff. Thus you need to mention "assume function $f$ to be defined in a certain neighborhood of $0$ except possibly at $0$". And also understand that these limit equalities work in a more general sense. You just add that "in a similar manner we can show that if one of the limits exists/diverges/oscillates the other also does the same".